# Drawing array of objects in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

What I have in my program right now: 
- When the mouse is clicked, a shape object is created and stored in an array. The constructor also draws the object just created to the screen. The first click makes a rectangle, the second click makes a circle, third click goes back to a rectangle, etc. 
- The array is circular, so when it reaches its max it goes back and replaces the first shape with whatever is next.

My program is that I'm trying to display 25 of those shapes at a time using a for loop as shown:

```
for (int i = 0; i < obj_count; i++) {
  if (objects[i].type == 0) {
      objects[i].drawRect();
  } else if (objects[i].type == 1) {
      objects[i].drawCirc();
  }
}
```

but when I run this, there is a lot of flickering and only one rectangle and some of the circles show up at a time. It works okay if I only try to show one shape at a time using an if statement to draw the last shape in the array though, so I'm not sure where the problem is coming from.

The rest of the relevant code is here:

```
void my_display(void) {
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) ;

for (int i = 0; i < obj_count; i++) {
      if (objects[i].type == 0) {
      objects[i].drawRect();
     } else if (objects[i].type == 1) {
      objects[i].drawCirc();
     }
 }  

glutSwapBuffers();  
return ;
}

void my_TimeOut(int id) { 
time += 1;
my_display();
glutTimerFunc(25, my_TimeOut, 0);
}
```

(the timer will be eventually used to make the shapes move)

In the object class:

```
void A1_Object::drawRect() {
//   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) ;
         glColor3f(0,0,1) ;
         glRectf(vertices[0], vertices[1], vertices[2], vertices[3]);
         glutSwapBuffers();
}

void A1_Object::drawCirc() {
//   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) ;
         glColor3f(1,0,0) ;

         int triangles = 50;
         GLfloat radius = 0.05; 
         GLfloat twoPi = 2 * 3.14159f;

         glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
            glVertex2f(center_x, center_y); 

            for (int i = 0; i <= triangles; i++) {
                glVertex2f(center_x + radius*cos(i*twoPi/triangles),     center_y + radius*sin(i*twoPi/triangles));
            }

        glEnd();            
//      glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, that'd be great! I can also post the full code if needed.

Comment: `A1_Object::drawRect` calls `glutSwapBuffers`.

Comment: If I don't include glutSwapBuffers in drawRect, then the circles show up okay with every other click, but the rectangles only flicker on the screen then disappear.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean? I used glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN); to draw the circles and had to end that block of code with glEnd();

Comment: I would chalk this up to drawing inside your timer function. Does not GLUT have a callback you can use when you need to repaint a window? You should do all of your drawing logic from there, and if you want to force a repaint at some interval you can just do `glutPostRedisplay ();` within your timer function.

Answer (score 2):

Updating and *drawing* your scene are two *very* different things. You need to understand how each framework treats these two app events. In some cases, OpenGL runs in its own thread, calling any "gl" method from another thread would break the call.

But I digress. Here's my $.02 on the matter of your conflict:

Order, structure and form are important!

glutTimerFunc -- designed for UPDATE part of your loop -- calling glutSwapBuffers in there is questionable at best.

Usually callback subscription when using GLUT goes like

```
glutDisplayFunc(display);           // opengl drawing goes here
glutTimerFunc(33, update_world, 0); // physics, ai, other stuff here

// .. callbacks ..

glutMainLoop();
```

At the end of your update method call **glutPostRedisplay()**

```
void update_world(int data) 
{
    glutTimerFunc(33, update, 69); // call update() every 33ms

    // code to update the world

    // ..

    glutPostRedisplay(); // <== !
}
```

**glutPostRedisplay()** works by setting a flag that tells **glutMainLoop** to execute the registered **display()** method in the next iteration step. If don't explicitly specify it, GLUT doesn't draw the next frame correctly.

Imagine leaving out glutPostRedisplay in update_world(data) from the example. Your world will appear frozen, with no animation even though the positions of your vectors/buffers will be changing! ( did I hear a penny drop? :) )

glutPostRedisplay makes the unrolled glutMainLoop run like

```
update_world(69);
display();
update_world(69);
display();
update_world(69);
display();
```

without it, glutMainLoop would just call

```
update_world(69);
update_world(69);
update_world(69);
```